# Changing the value of a list in a loop C++

Tags: c++

I need some help with C++ iterator and range-based list traversing and updating. I have the following code in C++ 11. The code below doesn't seem to modify the lists in place.

```
auto LIST1 = std::list<Myobject>;
auto LIST2 = std::list<Myobject>;
//Filled lists with Myobjects
// Now I need to swap some values in LIST1 with values in LIST2 if some condition is satisfied
std::list<MyObject>::iterator iter2 = LIST2.begin();
for (auto &el : LIST1){
    if (iter2 == LIST2.end()) {break;}
        if (el->getSomeProperty() <= 0){
            if (iter2->getSomeProperty() >= minValue){
                auto temp = el;
                el = *iter2;
                *iter2 = temp;
            }
            ++iter2; // The iterator moves forward;
        }
}
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks!
P.S: I am a newbie at StackOverflow so be gentle is I wasn't clear.

Comment: Your question implies that the posted code runs but doesn't provide the desired results. However, it doesn't compile. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This question does not leave me with a desire to rend human flesh, but to avoid making questions that do, take the [tour] and read [ask], [Writing the perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and [How To Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (to help avoid asking questions in the first place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue must be in code you haven't shown. The code you've shown works fine. Here's a fully-working skeleton that shows that the shown code works.

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::list<int> list1;
    std::list<int> list2;

    list1.push_back(10);
    list1.push_back(20);
    list1.push_back(30);

    list2.push_back(1);
    list2.push_back(200);
    list2.push_back(3);

    std::list<int>::iterator iter2 = list2.begin();
    for (auto &el : list1)
    {
        if (iter2 == list2.end()) {break;}
        {
            if (el > *iter2)
            {
                auto temp = el;
                el = *iter2;
                *iter2 = temp;
            }
            ++iter2; // The iterator moves forward;
        }
    }

    for (auto &el : list1)
        std::cout << "l1: " << el << std::endl;
    for (auto &el : list2)
        std::cout << "l2: " << el << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hi David, Thank you. My problem is that the "Myobject" class code is not visible to me. They come in a pre-compiled header and I am creating instances of them to process. Thank you for your help! I will on the object side then.

Comment: @Claver As a workaround, you could make the lists hold `std::unique_ptr<MyObject>`. That way, the swap would definitely swap the two objects without changing either of them.

Answer (score 0):

@David, Thank you again. I managed to fix the issues. The functional code is as shown below. Clearly, I messed up.

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class MyObject{
    int value;
public:
    MyObject(int m_value){
        value = m_value;
    }

    int getValue() const {return value;}

};


int main(){
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<MyObject>> list1;
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<MyObject>> list2;

    for (int i = 0; i > -10; i--){
        list1.emplace_back(std::make_shared<MyObject>(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        list2.emplace_back(std::make_shared<MyObject>(i));
    }

    int minValue = 5;
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<MyObject>>::iterator iter2 = list2.begin();
    for (auto &el : list1){
        if (iter2 == list2.end()) {break;}
            if (el->getValue() <= 0){
                if ((*iter2)->getValue() >= minValue){
                    auto temp = el;
                    el = *iter2;
                    *iter2 = temp;
                }
                ++iter2; // The iterator moves forward;
            }
    }

    for (auto &obj : list1){
        std::cout << obj->getValue() <<std::endl;
    }

};
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, you should mark the question as solved. Since David's answer explained the problem and lead you to this solution, you should chose David's answer as correct. This helps future programmers with a similar problem find these answers. Who wants to click on a question with no right answers?

Comment: I already upvoted @David's answer. My vote doesn't show because apparently I haven't earned enough stripes.

Comment: Claver, it you take the [tour] you should see what I am talking about. As the question asker there is an additional option, a big grey checkmark, Click it green. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This option might not have been there earlier to prevent askers from instantly accepting the first (and often not ready for prime-time) answer posted.